# How to Center a TextView Relative to Another - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

I have two TextView, one below the other with the property below

Now I want my top TextView to be centered over my bottom TextView

Here is my code for now

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Content of the Toast"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: use constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Use Constraint Layout for this purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/content_of_the_toast"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content_of_the_toast"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Content of the Toast"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Replace the tools:context=".MainActivity" of androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout by your activity java class.

Replace the android:id="@+id/content_of_the_toast"
of your bottom text view by any other id of your choice.

**Hope this helps...**